# Fetch records with MAX values between specific timestamp in accurate MAX order

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I am having some challenges spooling out some database records.

I need to get the rows with MAX value for a specific column and these records must fall between two timestamp values.

Here is the SQL query

```
SELECT id, MAX(amount), created 
FROM `product` 
where author = '1' AND (created BETWEEN '2018-02-03' AND '2018-02-08') 
GROUP BY id
```

I am able to get the records with MAX value in an accurate order using

```
SELECT id, MAX(amount), created FROM `product` where author = '1' GROUP BY id
```

But the moment I include a clause to distinct records between my desired timestamp, I lose the accurate order in MAX

Would be really glad to get some help with this. Thanks

Comment: What does "accurate MAX order" mean? Can you post some sample data and the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` then `ORDER BY` `MAX(amount)`

```
SELECT id, MAX(amount), created 
FROM `product` 
where author = '1' AND (created BETWEEN '2018-02-03' AND '2018-02-08') 
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch.. The `ORDER BY 1 DESC` was the game changer and I really like the approach and It just made me understood some basic things regarding record ordering in mysql... It simply changed from the default `ORDER BY id ASC` to yours... Thanks a million...